# How to remove line feed character in csv file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a csv data file with the data in the following structure:

```
abc^"a detail explaination"^cde^"another detail explaination"^date
```

However due to user input, some details were entered with a line breaks, and it broke the program. I'll need to remove those line breaks in between the double quote `"`

I tried to use the `sed` command but it doesn't change it, the command i tried is:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's@\(".*\)\n\(.*"\)@\1\\2@;t1' file.csv > file_changed.csv
```

The criteria that i'm trying to do is to replace the line breaks `\n` that is encapsulated in between 2 double quotes, as that is the format of the csv.

Anyone has any idea what's wrong with my `sed` command? Or is there other better way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Additional notes, i can't remove all line breaks as i'll need to keep those at the end of the line since this is a csv file for import purpose. Just need to remove those encapsulated within the double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':cycle^J/^\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*"[^"]*$/ {N;s/\n//;b cycle^J}' file.csv > file_changed.csv
```

On each line that have any number of open and close `"` + 1 `"`, add the next line, remove the line feed and retest. 
Print the resulting line and go to the next

Answer (score -1):

U can use : `tr -d '\n'` to remove all `\n`s if that is enough.

Comment: i can't as there are line breaks at the end of the line, and i'll need to keep those